# ZAP API context data isn't valid

Tags: java, api, zap

I am trying to automize pentesting with ZAP using the Java API. In the desktop app of ZAP I created a context, which is saved in the contexts directory of the OWASZP ZAP folder it created during the installation. Using the importContext function down below I think that I should receive the context.

```
context = new Context(ApiClient);
context.importContext("contextName.context");
```

Now it does find it, without the ".context" at the end it doesn't. It gives me an error message though.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.zaproxy.clientapi.core.ClientApiException: The external data provided is not valid.
    at org.zaproxy.clientapi.core.ApiResponseFactory.getResponse(ApiResponseFactory.java:50)
    at org.zaproxy.clientapi.core.ClientApi.callApi(ClientApi.java:351)
    at org.zaproxy.clientapi.gen.Context.importContext(Context.java:186)
    at jh.zap.main(main.java:14)
```

Does anybody know why? Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full path rather than just the name. If you look in the zap.log file it should give you more info, including the full file name it was actually trying.

Comment: In the .log file it says two things. The first is `ARN  API - Bad request to API endpoint [/xml/context/action/importContext/]`. I can't get anything useful from that. The second is this `A context with the given name [ContextName] already exists.`. This doesn't make very much sense to me because I'm trying to import an existing context with an import function.

Comment: I couldn't find a path anywhere in the zap.log file

Comment: What name is being used in the context file? If its 'Default Context' then it will clash with the existing one, if so just call it something else

Comment: It's not Default Context. I made a new one called sampleContext and searched for it using only 'sampleContext' which lead to no result (file not found) and for 'sampleContext.context' which lead to the mentioned error message.

Comment: It will be the name given in the file thats used, not the name of the file. Are you sure you dont have 2 contexts with the same name?

Comment: I only have this one context named that way. the only other contest is the default context.

Comment: I found the problem. Obviously it was open already when I just created it in the desktop app. Nevertheless, thank you for your Help! Now I know what you meant with two contexts with the same name.